# Linking with MS link and Netwide Assembler

Tags: windows, assembly, linker, nasm

Well i have some knowledge in x86 assembly. Now i want to lear x64 one.
I found a good tutorial here: https://sonictk.github.io/asm_tutorial/
But it uses the "Netwide Assembler". Have no problem with that. The thing is that i can create the ".obj" file with nasm.exe, but when linking with MS "link" it seems some libs are missing.
I'm trying to make a Win32 console app. So my hello.asm file is this:

```
bits 64
default rel

segment .data
msg db "Hello world!", 0xd, 0xa, 0

segment .text
global main
extern ExitProcess
extern printf

main:
     push    rbp
     mov     rbp, rsp
     sub     rsp, 32

     lea     rcx, [msg]
     call    printf

     xor     rax, rax
     call    ExitProcess
```

This is the example file of the first "hello world" .asm program.
But since i'm using win32 (ExitProcess) and C "printf" i have to link to libs that has de "definition" for this functions.

I don't know how to link it, the linker throws me "unresolved symbol" and it's not strange.
I took a look to Visual Studio 2019 paths, i opened a "Developer Prompt" for VS, but the problem persists.

The Question: How do i link this .obj file so MS linker produces the final .exe file. What option am i missing? Sorry to be so knoob, but i need some help.

Comment: No idea, but it might help someone else if you specify the exact commands you're trying to use.

Comment: 1 - Using: "nasm -f win64 -o hello_world.obj hello_world.asm"
Which sys "makes a x64 windows .obj file"
2 - "link hello_world.obj /subsystem:console /entry:main /out:hello_world_basic.exe"
Which tells the linker to link the .obj. Throws me "2 unresolved", one for "ExitProcess" and the other one for "printf".

Comment: Seems like you need to link against the `kernel32` and `msvcrt` libraries.